# Dynamically change background color of Gtk.Entry

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I am writing a GTK3 app in python and want to dynamically change the background color of an Entry based on certain other conditions in the application. All the documentation I've found seems to agree that CSS is the best way to do this, but that seems both too much overhead, and more permanent than I want.

I have tried override_background_color(), but this changes the highlight color rather than the empty space within the Entry field.

Is there a simple way to change the color around dynamically?

Comment: `override_background_color()` works here (`gtk3-3.11.5`). Edit: Actually it seems to be theme dependent. I'm not sure which is the correct behavior for the theme, but `override_background_color` changing the selection color doesn't really seem right. Anyway, I guess CSS is the only option you have.

Comment: GtkEntry is one hell of a widget. Really stuff to get with a bunch of  drawing layers. You should try with css by adding classes to your widget according to the state, and specify the classes statically on your css.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should prepare a css provider with as any many as tags as needed like:

```
#cond1 {
   background-image: none;
   background-color: .... ;
}
#cond2 {
   background-image: none;
   background-color: .... ;
}
#cond3 {
   background-image: none;
   background-color: .... ;
}
```

Then inside your code, each time you need a color matching your conditions, you just assign a name to your widget like:

```
widget.set_name("cond1")
```

And so on.

Regards

Comment: This was a GREAT idea! I never had the idea so far to just change .set_name() dynamically, like you suggested here. I am using ruby, so I have not tested it yet but I am writing a test-applicatioon to see if set_name() can be used a bit like javascript and CSS. :-)